# Query to delete single row in Impala

Tags: impala

I would like to delete on record from impala table. Below I have used to delete the record from the table.

This is My Query :

```
DELETE FROM sample.employee_details WHERE sno=5 AND name='XYZ'AND age=26;
```

suggest the best way to remove a record from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala delete command works only for Kudu storage type. Any storage formats other than kudu are not designed for online transactions and does not offer any real-time queries and row level updates and deletes.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine assuming your where conditions uniquely identify the row. See the documentation: 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_delete.html

Comment: Hi Bates, Thanks for your reply. I have gone through the documentation, it looks fine with query. Need to check why it is not working on impala.